# How a double pointer fetch the value from a single poiner

Tags: c++, pointers, double-pointer

An array is right now pointed by a single pointer. And a double pointer is pointing to the single pointer. I am trying to fetch the value of the array using this double pointer. As far I have only fetched the *first index value* of the array by the **double pointer**.
I know that if I dereference (`*ptr2`) a double pointer then it will give the address where the first pointer is pointed (`ptr1`) which means the first index address of the array(`&array[0]`).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int array[5]{15,25,35,45,55};
    int* ptr1;
    int** ptr2;

    ptr1 = &array[0];
    ptr2 = &ptr1;
```

In the following for loop, I have tried to print the value of `array` using pointer `ptr1`.

```
    for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"the value: "<<*(ptr1+i)<<" lives at "<<ptr1+i<<" address\n";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
```

In the following for loop I have tried to check `*ptr2` is all-time giving me address pointed by `ptr1` or not. But I have found that it only works/same for the first index then it is (`*ptr2`) giving me a different address

```
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        cout<<"adress of array: "<<&array[j]<<" , ptr1: "<<(ptr1+j)<<" , val of ptr2: "<<*(ptr2+j)<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

While I have tried to fetch the value from ptr2 by using `**ptr2+i` using a for loop it continues only for 2 times. First-time correct value which is obvious as I am seeing the address of `array[0]` and `*(ptr2+0)` are same. Second-time garbage value and then **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**.

One guess came in my mind that `ptr1` and `ptr2` both are `int` type but one is pointing to a variable and another is to a pointer. So maybe there is a memory allocation concept arises from the very beginning which I am skipped.

Is there any way where I can fetch the value of the array using the mentioned structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is close, but you did not apply it well.

> I know that if I dereference (`*ptr2`) a double pointer then it will give the address where the first pointer is pointed (`ptr1`)

In other words, `*ptr2` is a synonym for `ptr1`. So any place you see `ptr1` (after assigning `ptr2 = &ptr1`) you can substitute in `*ptr2`. Even better, substitute in `(*ptr2)` to avoid interference from operators with a higher precedence than de-reference. Let's take an example:

> ```
>    for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
>        cout<<"the value: "<<*(ptr1+i)<<" lives at "<<ptr1+i<<" address\n";
>    }
>    cout<<"\n";
> ```

Now do a simple find-and-replace. Replace `ptr1` with `(*ptr2)`. Don't try to adjust anything; once you've decided to do this, the process is mindless.

```
    for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
        cout<<"the value: "<<*((*ptr2)+i)<<" lives at "<<(*ptr2)+i<<" address\n";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
```

This is almost what you tried in your loop, except you used `*(ptr2+j)` instead of `(*ptr2)+i`. We can ignore the change from `i` to `j`, but those parentheses are significant. You changed the order of operations, which is comparable to using `3(1+4)` instead of `(3×1)+4`. It shouldn't be surprising that `15` does not work where `7` is needed, and similarly adding `j` before de-referencing does not work where the de-reference needs to be done first.

*Note: Since de-reference has a higher precedence than addition, the parentheses around `*ptr2` could be dropped from this particular example. That is, `*ptr2+i` and `*(*ptr2+i)` would also work.*

*Note: This question can serve as a demonstration of why it's often wise to avoid pointers-to-pointer.*

Answer (score 4):

`ptr2` is pointing at `ptr1`. `(ptr2+j)`, when `j` is not `0`, is an address you haven't allocated so dereferencing it (`*(ptr2+j)`) makes your program have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and getting a *Segmentation fault* is one possible outcome.

You should dereference it first, then index: `(*ptr2)[j]` or `*((*ptr2)+j)` if you will.